# returning address form a function

Tags: c

i have returned address form a function search(keys), like this

```
return ptr->keys[pos]
```

where ptr->keys[pos].value was used to access the member function of keys. is the above return statement correct? does this return the address  after it returns i have done

```
struct classifier keys,temp,*temp_ptr;
temp = search(key);
temp_ptr = &temp;
```

and then i am accessing the member function value of keys as

```
temp->value
```

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear.  What is `ptr`?  What is the type of `ptr->keys[pos]`?

Comment: ptr is pointer to struct node,and inside that structure there is struct classifier keys[2] which is a member function of struct node, so the type of ptr->keys[pos] is struct node

Comment: It is not return adress of variable if "keys" are **not** double pointer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, if pos is 0 or 1 then it's a valid index in keys and the return statement *is* ostensibly correct.  Please post realistic code though: the question's "struct classifier keys,..." is not reconcilable with "struct classifier keys[2]" mentioned in your comment above.  The following code is not correct: `temp = search(key);` tries to copy a pointer into a structure.  You might mean `temp = *search(key)`, which will copy the struct classifier's content out.  You can then use temp.value or temp_ptr->value but NOT temp->value as you asked.